# Sending PHP Variable within a JavaScript Alert / Confirm Box

Tags: php, javascript, variables, alert

I've been making steady progress up until the point I wanted the user to have a '**confirm**' alert before deleting a row via PHP. Essentially, I need to pass the variable of the row's id number to the 'delete.php' page once the user has pressed 'ok'.

So the PHP prints out a button:

```
$clickid = $db_field['id'];
    print "<form><input type='button' onclick='confirmation()' value='Delete'></form>";
```

And my Javascript:

```
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("You wish to delete this event?")
    if (answer){
        alert("Deleted")
        window.location = "http://www.xxxxxxx.co.uk/admin/delete.php<? "?id=$clickid "?>";
    }
    else{
        alert("Your Event is Not Deleted")
    }
}
</script>
```

It obviously runs through to the 'delete.php' page, but doesn't delete anything because $clickid seems to have no value passed to it. If anyone can spot where I am going wrong, or maybe something that would work, that would be great help.

Comment: remember semi-colons in javascript, the auto-insertion doesnt always work well

Comment: confusing that you tell the user the thing is deleted before you actually redirect. might want to write "Deleting" in that alert.

Comment: you need to post more code, there's no reason this shouldnt work.

Comment: remember that php and javascript have seperate interpreters and so on. i hope you assign the $clickid in your php code before you use it. might want to do ``set_error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)`` to check uninitialized var usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.location = "http://www.xxxxxxx.co.uk/admin/delete.php?id=<?php echo $clickid; ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = "http://www.xxxxxxx.co.uk/admin/delete.php<? "?id=$clickid "?>";
```

should this line not read more like this?

```
window.location = "http://www.xxxxxxx.co.uk/admin/delete.php?id="<?=$clickid ?>"";
```